# Footnote with a numbering style in \author

Tags: article, author

In LaTeX, I want to define the footnote numbering as a), b), c),... at the superscript of an author inside the `\author{}` command. If I use `\thanks` inside `\author{}`, the footnote numbering is different than a), b), c),... and I am unable to modify the numbering style of `\thanks` command.

Please see the code below and suggest an edit. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \title{Numbering footnote in author sample code}
    \author{AA \thanks{aa@email.com} \\
        BB \thanks{bb@email.com}}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footnote numbering of `\thanks` is set to `\@fnsymbol`, so you can probably replace it with `\@alph` to change it to alphabetical 'numbering'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@fnsymbol}[1]{\@alph{#1})}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \title{Numbering footnote in author sample code}
    \author{AA \thanks{aa@email.com} \\
        BB \thanks{bb@email.com}}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: first]

[image: footer]